# Maven Dependency Resolution with Projects Build Locally

Tags: maven

I have two projects A and B. Project A has a dependency on Project B. Right now both of them are on my machine and not on Nexus. I have included the GAV of Project B as a dependency in Project A. When I try to build Project A, the build fails as maven tries to download Project B jar from Nexus which doesn't exist there. However, Project B Jars are in local .m2 repo as I have already build the project. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried offline mode (`mvn -o`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the issue. Recently, I had an issue with my old MS Profile and a new profile was created. So, I had two local .m2 repositories one in the old profile and the other in the new profile. The Project B jars were getting created in the new repo, while Project A was trying to fetch jars from old repo. Changed the settings in Intellij and started working. Sorry for wasting everyone's time.